# Entity Framework Serializable Transaction Deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have to insert a row into the database but the problem is that the primary key is generated based on the total counts of rows. 
E.g. if the db has 25601 rows, the ID of the newly inserted record would be CT25602.

I want to use transactions for primary key collisions.
Here is the code I wrote.

```
public void CreateContact(ContactViewModel input)
{
    var transactionScopeOptions = new TransactionOptions
    {
        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable,
        Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue
    };

    using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionScopeOptions))
    {
        var contactNo = GenerateIdentity();
        var contact = MapContactFields(new NavContact { No_ = contactNo }, input);

        _db.Contacts.InsertOnSubmit(contact);
        _db.SubmitChanges();
        transaction.Complete();
    }
}
```

This code gives me deadlocks if two persons are trying to insert a contact in a small timespan.

Any suggestions ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the scenario you described is very likely to deadlock. I would recommend using a [sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) instead. If not, then one solution is to acquire an exclusive app lock in the transaction, *before* scannig for the next identity. See [`sp_getapplock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx).

Comment: Couldn't I use some kind of a "defer" mechanism like a retry executing the same operation in x seconds?